# Uniqueness of solution of differential equation $y'=y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In school, I have recently been learning about simple differential equations. We know that the solution of $y'=y$  is $y=Ae^x$, where $A$ is a constant. But how can we know that it is the **only** solution? The only thing I can figure out is that $y$ is continuously differentiable. Help me, please.

Comment: think of it this way, what function is its own derivative??

Comment: [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard–Lindelöf_theorem).

Answer (score 6):

Let $z$ be a solution to $y'=y$. Consider $z(t)e^{-t}$. We have
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(z(t)e^{-t})=z'(t)e^{-t}-z(t)e^{-t}=0,
$$
therefore 
$$
z(t)e^{-t}=Const\implies z(t)=Ae^{t}.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $y$ is a solution to $y'=y$

Multiply both sides by $e^{-x}$ to get $$ y'e^{-x} = ye^{-x}$$

$$y'e^{-x}-ye^{-x}=0$$

$$ \frac {d}{dx} (ye^{-x}) =0$$
$$ye^{-x} =A$$
$$ y=Ae^{x} $$

Answer (score 1):

I've heard this kind of question before. An anti-derivative will yield a definitive delta area under a graph of a function between any 2 limits. Seeing there is only one delta area, any different expressions defining it would essentially be the same.

The area of a right triangle $1/2xy$ or $1/2x^2 \tan \theta$ are the same with a trigonometric substitution. For the family of anti-derivatives whose only difference is C, where C makes no difference in calculating the definite integral, in reverse they only have one derivative.

To summarize, a function that defines areas of different regions under a graph is unique and so those different areas are themselves defined by a unique function under which they exist.

Comment: Thanks... but it's a little bit hard for me to understand. I should study more..

Comment: The question you were asking is essentially, will a different function yield the same areas between any 2 limits of integration?

Comment: Really the opposite, is there another function with the same slope change as the integral?

Answer (score -1):

Suppose there is another solution $y=f(x)$. Then we must have that $y=f(x)-Ae^x$ is a solution. Now working this out gives us:
$$y'=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(f(x) - A e^x) = f'(x) - A e^x$$
Note that we must have $y=y'$ so $f(x)=f'(x)$ clearly this only holds for $f(x) = A e^x$.

Comment: This is a circular argument.